# save MySQL rows in an array and save it in session variable

Tags: php, session-variables, associative-array

I want to get rows from MySQL Database and save two specific values(row[0] & row[6]) in $_SESSION variable for comparison later on.
The code looks like below:

```
        $sqlResult =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questionbank WHERE quizName ='$quizNames' ORDER BY RAND() limit 6")

    while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($sqlResult)) 
            {
                $questionPkId = $row[0];                    
                echo $_SESSION['$questionPkId'] = $row[6];

            }
```

The Problem is I can't get this values in other pages. Can I make an associative array with session variable (though i tried array_push(), But it did not work).

Comment: Did you make sure to call `session_start` on every page that uses `$_SESSION` ?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated. Also, a tip, don't `SELECT *` but write out the columns you need.

Comment: @Brad F : yes I did start session in all pages

Comment: Learn basic PHP syntax. `'$questionPkID'` is not going to evaluate to what you think it is...

Comment: @BartFriederichs Instead of mysql_* what should I use? Also I will need the row values later on. because I am planning to store values in one array and another one to display my questions and finally compare them to get the correct answer. Please advise (Thanks in advance)

Comment: @Samawat use MySQLi or PDO instead. And prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple issues with your code. First up, make sure you call `session_start` on any page that uses sessions. Without it, you will not be able to access the variables previously set.

Second up, when a variable is called inside single quotes it is taken literally, meaning your session define statement is always assigning the variable to same thing, and hence overwriting what it should be.

```
$_SESSION[$questionPkId] = $row[6];
```

And that will assign the value to the actual value of `$questionPkId`. Aside from those issues, your `session` items should work, and if they are not you will need to provide us with more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try without single quotes:

```
$_SESSION[$questionPkId] = $row[6];
```